# regular expression to find exact matching containing a space and a punctuation

Tags: r, regex, regex-negation, stringr

I am going through a dataset containing text values (names) that are formatted like this example :

```
M.Joan (13-2)  
A.Alfred (20-13)  
F.O'Neil (12-231)  
D.Dan Fun (23-3)
T.Collins (51-82) J.Maddon (12-31)
```

Some strings have two names in it like

```
 M.Joan (13-2) A.Alfred (20-13)
```

I only want to extract the name from the string.
Some names are easy to extract because they don't have spaces or anything.
However some are hard because they have a space like the last one above.

```
name_pattern = "[A-Z][.][^ (]{1,}"
base <- str_extract_all(baseball1$Managers, name_pattern)
```

When I use this code to extract the names, it works well even for names with spaces or punctuations. However, the extracted names have a space at the end. I was wondering if I can find the exact pattern of " (", a space and a parenthesis.

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Z.Taylor "

[[2]]
[1] "Z.Taylor "

[[3]]
[1] "Z.Taylor "

[[4]]
[1] "Z.Taylor "

[[5]]
[1] "Y.Berra "

[[6]]
[1] "Y.Berra "
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to remove final `(...)`? Use `sub("\\s*\\([^()]*\\)\\s*$", "", baseball1$Managers)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is easier however i am required to use str_extract_all, also, some of the names have two names like "T.Collins (51-82) J.Maddon (12-31)", and using that code would output: "T.Collins (51-82) and J.Maddon"

Comment: Try `name_pattern = "[A-Z][.][^\\s(]{1,}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
x <- c("M.Joan (13-2) ", "A.Alfred (20-13)", "F.O'Neil (12-231)", "D.Dan Fun (23-3)", "T.Collins (51-82) J.Maddon (12-31)", "T.Hillman (12-34) and N.Yost (23-45)")
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\p{Lu}.*?(?=\\s*\\()", x, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [regex demo](https://ideone.com/fP08hJ)

Or the `str_extract_all` version:

```
str_extract_all(baseball1$Managers, "\\p{Lu}.*?(?=\\s*\\()")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jxrr0u/1).

It matches

- `\p{Lu}` - an uppercase letter
- `.*?` - any char other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of (but not including into the match, as `(?=...)` is a non-consuming construct)....
- `(?=\\s*\\()` - positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, requires the presence of:

  - `\\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
  - `\\(` - a literal `(`.

Comment: strange, using the str_extract_all that you provided, some outputs this "T.Hillman"  "and N.Yost"

Comment: It is not strange. If names start with uppercase letters always, just replace `\p{L}` with `\p{Lu}`.

Comment: Great. If you ever want to experiment with `gregexpr`, and you have Unicode letters in the names, it is safer to add `(*UCP)` at the pattern start: `"(*UCP)\\p{Lu}.*?(?=\\s*\\()"`. You do not need that in *stringr* method as ICU regex is already Unicode aware. To some extent.